# Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. (" <div class="upload-right"> <div class="signup">

Tags: node.js, angular

I am using Angular 7. I don't know where the error occurs in this form. It always shows form is not a known property of this method. Where did I make a mistake in the below code? I am getting this error.

> Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'

```
        <form [formGroup]="newClientForm">
            <fieldset>
           <div class="row" style="text-align:center">

         <input type="text" class="st0" placeholder="Enter name" class="form-control"  name="name" formControlName="name" #name required="required" />

                   </div>
                     <br>
                     <div class="row" style="text-align:center">  
          <input type="text" class="st0" placeholder="Enter email" class="form-control"  name="email" formControlName="email" #email required="required" pattern="([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?" />
                       </div>
                       <br>
                <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
            <input type="password" class="st0" placeholder="Password" class="form-control"  name="password" formControlName="password" #password required="required" pattern=".{6,}"
              title="Minimum 6 characters required" autocomplete="off" />
                   </div>
                     <br>
                     <div class="row" style="text-align:center">

        <input type="text" class="st0" placeholder="Enter mobile" class="form-control"  name="mobile" formControlName="mobile" #mobile required="required" />
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
                                <!-- <input type="submit" value="Register" /> -->
                                <button type="submit" class="st1" value="register" (click)="register()">Register</button>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
                                <div class="forgot">
                                    <a href="#">Login?</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
```

Comment: Did you import the formsmodule or reactiveformsmodule?

Comment: yes i added in app.module.ts

Comment: show formGroup code of your .ts file

Comment: @malar, this is not the code where you give the error. Angular say you can't bind ... in a div class="upload" (in your code there're not such div)

Answer (score 0):

Try this stackblitz link [reactive form](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lfr8ny?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts). I have created a similar form using your html code and have run it. 
Things i did were very basics:
Imported ReactiveFormsModule from @angular/forms
and have created a formgroup in ts file and added all controls you used in your html.
It runs well. 
Let me know if your issue is different from the solution provided.

Comment: I don't know the where i did mistake